# French for 'It must be my imagination'?

Tags: expressions, anglais

*It looks like there are a lot less cars on the streets than usual, don't you think? No? Really? It must be my imagination, then.*

What is the usual French way for saying 'It must be my imagination' in a context like the above? I tried automatic translators among other things but I'm not convinced with the results I saw that seem way too literal for me. Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 10):

Some usuals French way for saying *« It must be my imagination. »* would be :

- Ce doit être mon imagination.

> On dirait qu'il y a beaucoup moins de voitures dans les rues que d'habitude, vous ne pensez pas ? Non ? Vraiment ? **Ce doit être mon imagination**, alors.

---

- Je dois me faire des idées.

> On dirait qu'il y a beaucoup moins de voitures dans les rues que d'habitude, vous ne pensez pas ? Non? Vraiment ? **Je dois me faire des idées**, alors.

---

- Mon imagination me joue sûrement des tours.

> On dirait qu'il y a beaucoup moins de voitures dans les rues que d'habitude, vous ne pensez pas ? Non ? Vraiment ? **Mon imagination me joue sûrement des tours.**

Comment: "Ce doit être mon imagination" seems to me much more frequent than any of the other two suggestions you wrote.

Comment: Merci pour votre retour, j'ai mis à jour la réponse en conséquence. :)

Comment: 'How many times would you actually say Ce instead of Ça in speech here?

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire (and the two comment upvoters) What makes you feel *ce doit être mon imagination* is more frequent than the other suggestions? I would on the opposite suspect it to be rarer, especially in spoken French, and *je dois me faire des idées* to be the more frequent.

Comment: @jlliagre My cultural background as a French-speaking Belgian.

Comment: @Lambie "Ce doit être..." is used when you use "it must be..." and "Ça doit être..." is used when you use "that must be..."

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire The difference is more about register than meaning. *Ce doit être...* is formal while *ça doit être...* is common, especially in spoken French.

Comment: C'est pour ça que j'ai quitté ce forum. On prends toujours les choses que je dis à l'envers.  Bien sûr, c'est une question de registre...

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure what you've found out on your own {Perhaps, "Ça doit être mon imagination"?}, but colloquially I'd more likely say something like:

> On dirait qu'il y a beaucoup moins de voitures qu'en temps normal dans les rues, tu ne trouves pas ? Non ? Ah bon, je dois **me faire des idées**, alors.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, DeepL translator doesn't seem to perceive an idiomatic turn (Ça doit être mon imagination.)

In French this locution would not be rendered best by a unique expression usable in any context. In the instance under consideration it can be translated as follows on the count of there being in the difference involved a real possibility for contending the fact; (the possibilities that'll be shown after confer somewhat too much intensity to the denial.)

- Ce doit être une impression. -- Ça ne doit être qu'une impression. -- Ce n'est que mon impression alors. (*and more variants*)

(*If the remark is made to the person, instead of their making it to themselves*)

- Ce doit être une impression (que vous avez/tu as). -- Ça ne doit être qu'une impression (que vous avez/tu as). . -- Ce n'est que votre/ton impression. (*and more variants*)

(*if there is no doubt at all*)

- Ce/Ça ne peut être que votre/ton impression.

When the a priori falsity of the fact is not subject to much contention although the expressions used in the first case can still be proper, other forms are more apt to emphasise that the situation is perceived falsely;

- Je dois me faire des idées.
- J'ai dû le rêver.
- Je dois rêver. -- Je rêve.

> Je rêve! Il n'y a plus un seul fruit dans la panière! Je croyais pourtant manger des fruits ce soir …

(*If the remark is made to the person, instead of their making it to themselves*)

- Vous vous faite des idées/Tu te fais des idées.
- Vous l'avez rêvé./Tu l'as rêvé.
- Vous rêvez./ Tu rêves.

> -- Je crois qu'il me hais, sans qu'il ait le courage de se détourner de moi, en réalité il me hais.
>   -- (Tu l'as rêvé)/(Tu te fais des idées), il ne vois que par toi, ne parle que de toi!

Answer (score 2):

To me, ça doit être mon imagination alors is perfect. Don't bother to pick any other translation. I'd word it this way in French.

Answer (score 2):

You might find "*Ce doit être mon imagination*" in a book, but I would never say that out loud.

@Con-gras-tue-les-chiens answer is quite good. You might also say:

> On dirait qu'il y a beaucoup moins de voitures que d'habitude dans
>   les rues, tu ne trouves pas ? Non ? C'est vrai ? Ça doit être juste une impression alors...

Comment: "Ce doit être mon imagination" looks perfectly correct to me, why recommending to never say that out loud?

Comment: It fits the written language, but it seems a bit sophisticated for spoken language. Especially given the content of the rest of the sentence. I would never say that, nor heard anyone say that around me in this kind of conversation.

Comment: Curious, we must have different uses depending on the region.

Comment: And not the same relatives, same age, same job ;)

Comment: Though, I still think that the use of `ça` instead of `ce` would be found more frequently in spoken language. Moreover, `Ce doit être` seems sophisticated to me compared to `c'est peut-être`. I also find more frequently `imagination` be mentioned when referring to fantasy, fears, hallucinations, whereas `impression` and `se faire des idées` seems more common and neutral to me.

Comment: Hi, welcome to French SE! I recommend you use _italics_ for quotations or for mixing languages. `monospace` is very useful for anything related to programming but it doesn't fit that well for anything else. I often omit them when it's just words, but you can also use quotation marks for full sentences :)

Comment: Noted. Thanks :)

Comment: I second Ced on that one. Looks alright to me and not that sophisticated either...

Answer (score 2):

"Cela doit être le fruit de mon imagination" est une autre expression courante

Answer (score 1):

Another frequent alternative is:

> C'est sans doute mon imagination.
>   <sub>([3220 hits on Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22C%27est+sans+doute+mon+imagination.%22))</sub>